# Why is screen drawing on mobile devices considered "expensive"?

Tags: android, ios, jquery-ui, hardware, screen

I always see people talking at GoogleIO or WWDC about how drawing the screen(bits/pixels) on mobile devices is *so* expensive. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Depends on the context. You might wanna show where you heard/read that.

Comment: Expensive in terms of what? Battery life? CPU? GPU? I know the screen in general being used is expensive for battery life. In terms of performance as mibollma said it defiantly depends on context, weather you are using native gui drawing or doing OpenGL rendering can make a huge difference.

Comment: [This](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/3d-graphics-on-android-lessons-learned-from-google-body.html) is an example. They just talk about how expensive of a process it is. Expensive in terms of speed(its a slow process, apparently).

Comment: different people may likely be talking about different things, context is king, got any direct quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pixel drawing does not make use of any graphic acceleration hardware. For instance, pixel drawing in Java is executed using the general purpose instruction set of the device. For instance, creating the text I'm writing pixel by pixel in Java would be very slow. Instead, the graphics acceleration hardware pipeline allows moving of many pixel at the time and also allows for drawing geometrical objects using special hardware operators on the mobile chip (like for instance the Tegra chip). This goes for Androids and Apple devices as well as for some graphics frameworks on desktop computers.

Sometimes you will have no choice, but as a role of thumb, try to use the higher level API's to draw to the screen as they will have a chance to map to the hardware accelerated capabilities of your device.